# Data is not Showing in the DataGridView

Tags: c#, sql-server, database, visual-studio-2019, windows-forms-designer

I have written a windows project using Visual Studio. My data entries are successfully added to my database. Even my database full of data this data grid

[image: this is my database]

view is not showing my data. But if I try to get the data from the database in my data grid view it wasn't showing.

I tried several times and it won't work.

My form that shows the data

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using Ttable.Asram;
using WinFormsApp1;

namespace Ttable
{
    public partial class Demo : Form
    {
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=DESKTOP-OGS07R8\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=TimeTable;Integrated Security=True");
        SqlCommand cmd;
        SqlDataAdapter adapt;

        //ID variable used in Updating and Deleting Record  
        int ID = 0;

        public Demo()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
           
        }

        private void button14_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void button15_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
           
        }

        private void Demo_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void dataGridView1_CellContentClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
        {
                ShowData();
        }

        private void ShowData()
        {
            con.Open();
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            adapt = new SqlDataAdapter("select * from AddWork", con);
            adapt.Fill(dt);
            dataTable.DataSource = dt;
            
            con.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What is `dataTable`?  It doesnt appear to be the name of the `DataGridView` - it appears you never set the grid's datasource

Comment: Why would you call `ShowData();` in the CellContentClick event?  Move that line to after `InitializeCompotent();`

Comment: When try to bind the datasource to a DataGridView, you don't need to add any columns to it. So the event `CellContentClick` won't be triggered. You should call `ShowData()` after `InitializeComponent();`. Besides, you need to set `dataGridView1.DataSource`, rather than `dataTable`.

Comment: @KyleWang dataTable is my dataGridView1 Name

Comment: @ŇɏssaPøngjǣrdenlarp its my DataGridView name